# Sorting data in combobox case insensitive

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, combobox

I'm trying to make a combobox that gets its values from a range. I only want to see unique values and it must be sorted in alphabetical order (case insensitive).

Everything works fine except the sorting of data. Sorting is case sensitive but this is not what I want.

Sorting is like:

```
Door
Room
Window
kitchen
```

But the way I want it:

```
Door
kitchen
Room
Window
```

Below you can find my code:

```
Dim x, a, b As Long, c As Variant    
 Dim DataRng As String

 Worksheets("House").Activate    

 'Unique Records    
 For x = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row    
     If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D2:D" & x), Cells(x, 4)) = 1 Then    
         ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(x, 4).Value    
     End If    
 Next

 'Alphabetic Order    

 For a = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1    
   For b = a To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1    
        If ComboBox1.List(b) < ComboBox1.List(a) Then    
            c = ComboBox1.List(a)    
            ComboBox1.List(a) = ComboBox1.List(b)    
            ComboBox1.List(b) = c    
       End If    
   Next    
  Next 
End Sub
```

I hope someone can solve my problem or can give me a hint.

Comment: try `ucase(ComboBox1.List(b))...` or `option compare text` perhaps

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So easy (once you know how to do it :-) ) I changed my code into:  If UCase(ComboBox1.List(b)) < UCase(ComboBox1.List(a)) Then ...

Answer (score 0):

try `ucase(ComboBox1.List(b))...` or `option compare text perhaps`